# Cannot access ifreq structure definition, __USE_MISC macro undefined

Tags: c, linux, sockets

I am trying to compile the following single C file (called main.c):

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define __USE_MISC 1
#include <net/if.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
ifreq id_ifreq;
fprintf(stdout, ">>>>>> OK <<<<<<\n");
}
```

... using "gcc main.c -o main". I get the following error:

```
main.c: In function ‘main’:
main.c:9:2: error: unknown type name ‘ifreq’
```

I know that "ifreq" structure definition lies within a "#ifdef __USE_MISC" macro, however, I cannot activate that block of code.

I developed the following code for checking which MACROS are defined (compiled with "gcc main.c -o main"):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <net/if.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{

   #ifdef __USE_MISC
       printf("__USE_MISC defined\n");
   #endif
   #ifdef _GNU_SOURCE
       printf("_GNU_SOURCE defined\n");
   #endif

   #ifdef _BSD_SOURCE
       printf("_BSD_SOURCE defined\n");
   #endif

   #ifdef _SVID_SOURCE
       printf("_SVID_SOURCE defined\n");
   #endif

}
```

The result is that they are all defined but the "_GNU_SOURCE" one. However, I am still not capable of using the definition of the "ifreq" structure included in the "net/if.h" file.

Anybody can help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are omitting the `struct` keyword (in C, a struct definition is **not a typedef**)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <net/if.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
struct ifreq id_ifreq;
fprintf(stdout, ">>>>>> OK <<<<<<\n");
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Correct, thank you very much for your help, I did not see the code inside "net/if.h", I though that it should have been defined with typedef... thanks again!